# Как задать абсолютный путь внутри класса?

Tags: php

Как мне задать абсолютный путь до папки внутри класса, чтобы загружать картинки для товаров?

```
    private $title;
    private $price;
    public $image;

    private $target_path =  "../images/"
}
```

Comment: вынесите настройки путей в файл конфигурации, не надо это задавать в каких-либо классах

Comment: `__DIR__ . '../images/'`

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте значение в свойстве например `private $target_path =  "/absolute/path/to/images/"` или инициализируйте значение в конструкторе класса.